# Javascript for loop behaving strange

Tags: javascript

I have a `for` loop to loop through the node which is `<ul>` that has 5 `<li>` elements.
I am trying to create a `div` for each of those `li` elements

When I try to append the `li` elements to `div` then the for loop is behaving strange

```
for (var i = 0; i < docNodes.children.length; i++) {
        var docs = document.createElement('div');
        docs.appendChild(docNodes.children[i]); //If this line is removed then it loops 5 times else it loops only 3 times
    }
```

Could someone let me know what is wrong with the code

Comment: `docNodes.children.length` is getting modified when you are moving the `li` from `ul` to `div`.

Comment: Also you cannot directly append a li to a div, or rather you shouldn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior isn't that weird. You're changing the length of `docNodes.children` in every iteration of the loop. For the next iteration, it checks the length again:

```
i | Length | i < length
0     5        true
1     4        true
2     3        true
3     2        false // Loop stops before the 4th iteration.
```

The reason the length is changing, is because `docs.appendChild` actually *removes* the target element from it's previous parent.

A way to work around this issue, it to iterate over the children in the opposite order:

```
for (var i = docNodes.children.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    var docs = document.createElement('div');
    docs.appendChild(docNodes.children[i]);
}
```

```
i | Length | i >= 0
4     5       true
3     4       true
2     3       true
1     2       true
0     1       true
-1    0       false // Loop stops before the 6th iteration.
```

Comment: for (var i = docNodes.children.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        var docs = document.createElement('div');
        docs.appendChild(docNodes.children[i]);
    }

<!-- language: lang-none -->

    i | Length | i >= 0
    4     4      true
    3     3      true
    2     2      true
    1     1      true
    0     0      true

Comment: then one element would be missed because index starts with 4 and goes till zero

Comment: Yea, I made a small mistake. Should've been `>=`

Answer (score 2):

As other point out you modify the length of the array during the loop.
In JavaScript it's better to use [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of an old fashioned for loop.

For example:

```
docNodes.children.forEach(function (child) {
    var docs = document.createElement('div');
    docs.appendChild(child);
});
```

Comment: @Cerbrus it was a copy paste mistake ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try this. And apply similar logic into your code.

```
<div id="list"></div>

<script>
let children = ['1','2','3','4','5'];

for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  var node = document.createElement("LI");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(children[i]);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("list").appendChild(node);
}
</script>
```

Comment: That `children` array is functionally very different than a DOM element's `children` property.

Comment: I know. But i was trying to provide similar answer to question. It might help solve the problem

Comment: The problem is in what the effect of `appendChild` is on `docNodes.children`. Replacing `docNodes.children` with an static array doesn't really help.